# Rails and Devise killed validation errors everywhere else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, devise

Is it possible that installing Devise 1.1.8 in a Rails 3.0.3 app, it somehow interferes with normal validations in non-devise models/controllers?

In my app, there's a User model tied to Devise.  In addition, there's a Patient model with an attribute: mobile.  (We collect the mobile number of patients for a healthcare app.)

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base

#validates_presence_of :mobile, :message => "must be provided"

end

The above throws the following error:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.errors

-- and --
Extracted source (around line #12):

```
9:       <h2><%= pluralize(@patient.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this subscriber from being saved:</h2>
10: 
11:       <ul>
12:       <% @subscriber.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
13:         <li><%= msg %></li>
14:       <% end %>
15:       </ul>
```

BTW, Devise works fine in displaying error messages when a new User makes an error (like not providing a password).

Also, removing :message => "must be provided" produces the exact same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@subscriber and @patient are different instance variables. You probably meant to use only one of them, and make sure it is actually initialized.

Comment: Argh...you are exactly right.  When I changed 'subscriber' to 'patient', it worked beautifully.  I can't believe I did that.  Thanks!